# How to checkout a specific SHA in a git repo using golang

Tags: go, go-git

I need help in check out the code upto a specific SHA number of git repo using golang

Comment: What it has to do with `go-lang`?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a Go question since it is referring to the `go-git` [library](https://github.com/src-d/go-git).

As such, you could do something like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

     git "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"
     "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing"
)

// Basic example of how to checkout a specific commit.
func main() {
    // Clone the given repository to the given directory
    r, err := git.PlainClone("your-local-repo-name", false, &git.CloneOptions{
        URL: "your-repo-clone-URL",
    })
    // handle error

    // ... retrieving the commit being pointed by HEAD
    ref, err := r.Head()
    // handle error

    w, err := r.Worktree()
    // handle error

    // ... checking out to commit
    err = w.Checkout(&git.CheckoutOptions{
        Hash: plumbing.NewHash("your-specific-commit-hash"),
    })
    // handle error

    // ... retrieving the commit being pointed by HEAD, it shows that the
    // repository is pointing to the giving commit in detached mode
    ref, err = r.Head()
    // handle error

    fmt.Println(ref.Hash())
}
```

**Note:** *the majority of this code was taken from the `go-git` library [examples](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/blob/master/_examples/checkout/main.go) directory and starts the entire process by cloning the repository into a new local directory; skip this step if not applicable to your use case.*